# Vectorizing matlab column normalization

Tags: matlab, normalization, vectorization

I want to normalize a matrix per column. I now have this code which works fine:

```
A = randn(10,3)

maxA = max(A,[],1)
minA = min(A,[],1)

for i=1:size(A,2)
    A(:,i) = (A(:,i) - minA(i) ./ (maxA(i) - minA(i))
end
```

However, since my matrix will be much bigger, about 10k by 60k looping will take forever. How could I vectorize my code?
I have thought of using Matlab's `normc` but that does not do the same as my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `bsxfun`

```
A = randn(10,3)

maxA = max(A,[],1)
minA = min(A,[],1)

bsxfun(@minus, A, minA ./ abs(maxA - minA))
```

However, I do not quite understand your normalizing. Wouldn't one rather use

```
(A(:,i) - minA(i)) ./ (maxA(i) - minA(i))
```

to normalize? If so, the `bsxfun` statement should read:

```
bsxfun(@times, bsxfun(@minus, A, minA), 1./abs(maxA - minA))
```

Comment: Indeed you are right about the normalization. I actually did it correct in Matlab but I copied it incorrectly when manually typing it. The method works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In general it could be:

```
A = (A - ones(size(A)) * diag(minA)) / diag(maxA - minA);
```

or

```
A = (A - ones(size(A)) * diag(minA)) * diag(1 ./ (maxA - minA));
```

but taking into account the size:

```
m = repmat(minA, size(A, 1), 1);
n = repmat(maxA - minA, size(A, 1), 1);
A = (A - m) ./ n;
```